# Export Angular2 componentes to another application

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have a project created through the Angular CLI, with a simple button component.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pf-button',
  templateUrl: './pf-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pf-button.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PfButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() layout: string;

}


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
[(ngModel)]="singleModel" btnCheckbox
btnCheckboxTrue="1" btnCheckboxFalse="0">
{{value}}
</button>
```

Now I want to create a new project through the Angular CLI and use this my previously created component. How can I do this?

Doing this locally, without getting into the merits of NPM or similar.

Comment: do you mean a new project or new module?

Comment: A new project. I want to use this 'PfButton' component in several other projects.